# Passing login Email from one class to another

Tags: java

I am trying to pass the login string from 1 class to another. Here is the class that it is entered:

```
package myFlight;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Login extends myFlightMain{
    
    @FXML
    private TextField UserPassword;
    
    @FXML
    public Label loginLbl;
    
    public String enteredPassword;

    //When Login is pressed gets the entered email and password, Sends them to check Login, also authenticates if admin.
    public void Login(ActionEvent event) {  
        String enteredEmail = UserEmail.getText();
        String enteredPassword = UserPassword.getText();
        VerifyLogin(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
        BookFlightsController callClass = new BookFlightsController();
        callClass.usersEmail(enteredEmail);
        UserPassword.setText("");
    }
    
    
    

    //Changes to register scene using Register button on Login screen
    public void loginRegisterButton(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Register.fxml"));
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          }
    }
    
    public void forgotPasswordButton(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ForgotPassword.fxml"));
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          }
    }
    

    /*public void ReturnToLogin(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/myFlight/Views/Login.fxml"));
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception f) {
          }
    }*/
    
    
    public void VerifyLogin(String enteredEmail, String enteredPassword) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
            //queries the database and gets the password from the Login table
            PreparedStatement CheckLogin = (PreparedStatement) conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT Password FROM Login WHERE CustomerEmail ='" + enteredEmail + "' ");
            //queries the database and checks the admin table for a yes or no
            PreparedStatement adminCheck = (PreparedStatement) conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT Admin FROM Login WHERE CustomerEmail ='" + enteredEmail + "' ");
            ResultSet rs = CheckLogin.executeQuery();
            ResultSet res = adminCheck.executeQuery();
                        
            if (res.next() && rs.next()) {  
                String admin = res.getString("Admin");
                String psw = rs.getString("Password");
                    
                //if username and password match and admin is set to yes, sends to Admin UI
                if (admin.equals("Yes") && psw.equals(enteredPassword)) {
                    AdminLoginComplete();
                }
                
                //if username and password match and admin is set to no, it sends user to Customer UI
                else if (psw.equals(enteredPassword) && admin.equals("No")) {
                    LoginComplete();
                } 
                
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          }
    }
    
    //Loads Admin UI
    public void AdminLoginComplete() {
        try {
            Stage login = new Stage();
            Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Admin.fxml"));
            Scene returnToLogin = new Scene(root1, 800, 600);
            returnToLogin.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            login.setScene(returnToLogin);
            login.show();
            
        } catch (Exception f) { 
          }
    }
    
    //Loads Customer UI
    public void LoginComplete() {
        try {
            Stage login = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CustomerInterface.fxml"));
            Scene returnToLogin = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
            returnToLogin.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            login.setScene(returnToLogin);
            login.show();
        } catch (Exception f) {

        }
    }
    
    
    //Sets the Login label after register is complete
    public void registerComplete() {
        loginLbl.setText("Registration Successful");
    }
}
```

Here is the class I am trying to pass it to:

```
package myFlight;

import java.awt.Label;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class BookFlightsController implements Initializable {

    

    @FXML
    private TableView<flightTable> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightTable, Integer> colFlightID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightTable, String> colFromCity;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightTable, String> colToCity;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightTable, String> colFlightDate;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightTable, String> colFlightTime;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<flightTable, Integer> colSeats;
    
    private String userEmail;
    private String enteredUserEmail;

    public List<flightTable> getAllFlightInfo() {
        
    
        List ll = new LinkedList();
        try {

            Connection conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from Flight");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                int flightID = rs.getInt("FlightID");
                String fromCity = rs.getString("FromCity");
                String toCity = rs.getString("ToCity");
                String flightDate = rs.getString("FlightDate");
                String flightTime = rs.getString("FlightTime");
                int numberOfSeats = rs.getInt("numberOfSeatsTotal");
                
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select " +flightID + " from BookedFlights");
                ResultSet rst = ps.executeQuery();
                int numberOfPassengers = 0;
                
                if (rst.next()) {
                    ++numberOfPassengers;
                }
                
                int seatsLeft = numberOfSeats - numberOfPassengers;
                
                
                ll.add(new flightTable(flightID, fromCity, toCity, flightDate, flightTime, seatsLeft));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return ll;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        colFlightID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<flightTable, Integer>("flightID"));
        colFromCity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<flightTable, String>("fromCity"));
        colToCity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<flightTable, String>("toCity"));
        colFlightDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<flightTable, String>("flightDate"));
        colFlightTime.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<flightTable, String>("flightTime"));
        colSeats.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<flightTable, Integer>("seatsLeft"));
        table.getItems().setAll(getAllFlightInfo());
    }
    
    public void bookAFlight(ActionEvent event) {

        flightTable selectedFlight = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        int selectedFlightId = selectedFlight.getFlightID();
        String selectedFromCity = selectedFlight.getFromCity();
        String selectedToCity = selectedFlight.getToCity();
        String selectedFlightDate = selectedFlight.getFlightDate();
        String selectedFlightTime = selectedFlight.getFlightTime();
    
        }

}
```

I also have this getter and setter setup if it would help:

```
package myFlight;

public class Loginset {
    
    private String userEmail;

    public Loginset() {
        
    }
    
    public Loginset(String userEmail){
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }
    
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }
    
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }
}
```

I have tried various ways of passing it and have not been able to get it. I need to use the email in the

public void bookAFlight(ActionEvent event) {

```
    flightTable selectedFlight = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int selectedFlightId = selectedFlight.getFlightID();
    String selectedFromCity = selectedFlight.getFromCity();
    String selectedToCity = selectedFlight.getToCity();
    String selectedFlightDate = selectedFlight.getFlightDate();
    String selectedFlightTime = selectedFlight.getFlightTime();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer that is a behavioral design pattern. It specifies communication between objects: observable and observers. An observable is an object which notifies observers about the changes in its state.

For example, you can create an interface to define this behavior design:

```
public interface OnChangeLoginStatus {

    void onChangeLoginStatus(String userEmail);
   
}
```

In your Login class

```
    import myFlight.OnChangeLoginStatus;
    
    private static ArrayList<OnChangeLoginStatus> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void addOnChangeLoginStatusListener(OnChangeLoginStatus newListener) {
            listeners.add(newListener);
        }
    
    
    private static void notifyAllListeners(String userEmail) {
            for (OnChangeLoginStatus listener : listeners) {
                listener.onChangeLoginStatus(userEmail);
            }
        }

    public void VerifyLogin(String enteredEmail, String enteredPassword) { ...
          try{...
               notifyAllListeners(enteredEmail); // allways when you call this method, all listeners will be informed about entered email or about whatever you want . . .
              }...
     }
```

in your BookFlightsController class

```
import myFlight.Login;
import myFlight.OnChangeLoginStatus;

private static String userEmailFromLoginClass;

public void initialize() {
        Login.addOnChangeLoginStatusListener(new OnChangeLoginStatus() {
            @Override
            public void onChangeLoginStatus(String userEmail) {
                 userEmailFromLoginClass = userEmail;
             }
        });
 }
```

And an another approach and option for Login.addOnChangeLoginStatusListener method in your BookFlightsController class, you can use a lambda expression to improve code readability if you want . . .

```
Login.addOnChangeLoginStatusListener(
        userEmail -> userEmailFromLoginClass = userEmail 
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am on mobile I found it difficult to look into your code. But from what ever I understood, dependency injection is what is required.

Inject the instance to whose method you want to pass on the login credentials in the class from where you want to pass on the credentials.

Comment: the issue I am having is passing it with 2 actionevents.